# referencing feature module routes in angular 2+

Tags: angular

I'm relatively new to angular 4. I'm wondering what's the best practice for being able to use a route from across feature modules?

So my app has:

- App Module - The main parent application.
- Core Module - Provides routes like signin, signout etc.
- UI Module - Has components like header, footer etc.

Inside each of App & Core I have corresponding route modules:

- App-Routing.module
- Core-Routing.module

Currently to be able to build router links in the `UI Module` I need access to the router definitions, so I:

1. Import the core-routing module into app-routing-module.
2. Then import the app-routing module into the UI Module.

This works, but I feel like it's not the `right` composition to be including things from App in child components...but if I don't import it, the `routerLink` references do not work in the UI module.

Is there a better way?

Comment: you have placed child routes in each of the feature modules i guess right ?

Comment: Yes correct. But I want to reference those routes from a sibling module.

Comment: yes it can be done , i have done it in one my git projects shall i share the link